# How to pass data from page to page using path in VUE js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently , i have two pages which consisted of add and edit page. I want to push my data from edit page to add page. So when i click save button in `edit page` , it will redirect user to back `add page` and the url will be `/test/admin/testing/add?visit_status=39`. How do i retrieve this data using ID from my edit page to add page ?

`edit.vue`

````
this.$router.push({path: '/test/admin/testing/add', query:{visit_status:this.$route.params.id}})```
````

Comment: with `this.$route.query.visit_status`

Comment: do i put this under `mounted()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get query data like the following. You can use for route jobs with **this.$route**. Click [here](https://router.vuejs.org/) for more information.

```
data(){
    return{
      visitStatus:null
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.visitStatus=this.$route.query.visit_status
  },
```

Or:

You can use this directly.

```
methods:{
    test(){
      if(this.$route.query.visit_status){
        //process
      }
       
    }
  },
```

Comment: using the methods helps. thank you